# jQuery: Multiple file upload with captions

Tags: php, jquery

I've been trying to make a multiple file uploader with a caption for each image without using any third-party plugin. I'm rather new to this and I don't completely understand what I'm doing here. I've taken snippets from different sources and I've been tweaking it around. So far, I've managed to make a form appear for each image that I dropped into the droparea, this form includes an input field for the image caption and an upload button. Individually, each of these newly spawned forms are successfully sending the image and the caption over to my `php` upload script. However, when I add an Upload All button, all I am able to send is the array of images without the captions. Can anybody give a clue on how to proceed further? I've googled around and tried to implement different approaches, but I keep failing. At the moment, I'm not concerned with browser-compatibility, I just want to make this work on Chrome and/or Firefox.

Here is my `upload.js` file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
    var fileList = new Array();
    $("#droparea").bind('dragenter dragover', false).bind('drop', function(e){

        $.each(e.dataTransfer.files, function(index, file){
            fileList.push(file);
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            fileReader.onload = (function(e){

                var form = document.createElement('form');
                form.action = 'uploads';
                form.className = 'forms';

                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = e.target.result;
                img.width = 80;

                var label = document.createElement('label');
                $(label).append('Image Caption');

                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.type = "text";
                input.name = "title";
                input.value = "";

                var button = document.createElement('button');
                $(button).append('Upload');
                $(form).append(img);    
                $(form).append(input);              
                $(form).append(button);             

                $('#uploads').append(form);
            });
        });

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

    });

    $('#upload-all').on('click', function(e){

        //upload all images with captions

    });

    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //var index what does this do?
        var index = $(this).index();
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        formData.append('file', fileList[index]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', 'upload.php', true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
});
```

My upload template file is

```
<div id="droparea" class="droparea">
    Drop files here to upload
</div>
<div id="uploads">

</div>
<button id="upload-all">Upload All</button>
```

My `upload.php` file simply prints the array of `$_FILES` and `$_POST`

Many thanks

Comment: It looks like the button event handler is inside the drag & drop event handler, binding a new event handler on every drop. Also, `fileList` contains a list of files, yet you're somehow only appending one file to the formData based on the index of the button, which seems strange ?

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. The first time I did that, I positioned the `fileList` array declaration outside of the drag&drop event handler. When I moved it inside the drag&drop handler, the submit event couldn't detected the `fileList` array, so it's my bad moving the button event handler inside the drag&drop not the other way around. I fixed that now. However my problem remains, now I don't even know how I sent the array of files over. I'll keep fiddling.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've managed to get it working, or at least it's how I wanted it to work. Here's my new modification.

```
$('#upload-all').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();     
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);    
    $('form').each(function(i){
        var title = $(this).find('input').val();
        formData.append('file[]', fileList[i]);
        formData.append('title[]', title);
    }); 

    upload(formData);
});

function upload(data) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('post', 'upload.php', true);
    xhr.send(data);

}
```

I also changed the single button event handler to call the upload function so I didn't have to repeat writing the XHR instantiation. If this isn't the right way to do it, I'll gladly give another go at any ideas thrown at me.